# How to make my page display the updated transactions

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

The following code grab information from a server and displays it on my page. It works fine but only one the first try.

For example the first time I open this page,

I get the info:

Gas Bill
Date: 13/05/14
Transaction Type: bank
Amount: $1.00

After that if I go to another page update some transactions and come back to this page, it will not show the updated information and only display the 'Gas Bill' information above. If I close my application all together, and restart it, the updated information will appear.

Is there anything I could add to my current code so that it instantly displays updated information everytime I visit this transactions page without having to close and restart my applicaion everytime? Tnks.

```
    $(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#transaction" ,function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $('#transaction').find('.ui-content').empty(); 
    //Transaction
    $.getJSON(theUrl + "user/transactionlog/", function (data) {
        //Loop for each element on the data
        $.each(data, function (elem) {
            var wrap = $("<div/>").attr('data-role', 'collapsible');
            //Create the h1 and the other elements appending them to transactions List
            $("<h1/>", {
                text: data[elem].reference
            }).appendTo(wrap);

            $("<p/>", {
                text: "Date: " + data[elem].date
            }).appendTo(wrap);

            $("<p/>", {
                text: "Transaction Type: " + data[elem].account
            }).appendTo(wrap);

            $("<p/>", {
                text: "Amount: \u00A3" + data[elem].amount
            }).appendTo(wrap);
            wrap.appendTo('#transactionList');
        });//end of for loop
        $( "#transactionList" ).collapsibleset();
    });//end of transaction page update
});
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="transaction" data-theme="e">
            <header data-role="header">
            <h1>Transaction</h1>    
        </header>
        <article data-role="content">
            <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" id="transactionList">
                <!--wil fill up with info from database-->
            </div>
        </article>
        <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <h1></h1>
        </footer>
        </div>
    <!--End of transaction page-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your are using **pageinit** event. It will trigger only once, basically it is a jQuery Mobile alternative to jQuery document ready.

What you need is page event that triggers each time page is visited. Best bet would be **pagebeforeshow** or even **pageshow** but you can decide which one best suits you.

Read more about it **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/page-events-order-in-jquery-mobile/)**. Or if you want to see some working example take a look **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**.

#### Update:

If you want to remove old content just use this line:

```
$('#pageID').find('.ui-content').empty();
```

or you can use this one:

```
$.mobile.activePage.find('.ui-content').empty();
```

of course last line will work if activa page is page where you are showing your content.

before you add new content.

Comment: hm I tried with pagebeforeshow and pageshow, it shows the updated information but now I end up getting duplicates. Gas Bill appears twice.

Comment: That's to be expected, you never removed old content.

Comment: Hi, tried them both. The page returns an empty page right from the start now and adding new content doesn't add update too

Comment: Then make it work, I gave you more then enough information so you can understand whats wrong. Can't help you more without looking at your code. It would be nice if you could also add HTML of your #transaction page.

Comment: Guess it is deviating to another question anyway, tks.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably being cached by the browser. Try setting:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Before making the request. You can use [jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) with JSON data type if you dont want this global setting.

If it does not work you might have to append some random characters to url to ensure it is fetching fresh version. EG: url.com/file?34244ff232

Comment: sure, as long as it is before your getJSON call

Comment: Yup tried that. Still same results, it doesn't show updated info.

Comment: and what if you add random data like: user/transactionlog/?dasf=2322